# Unable to record from USB microphone on Chrome on Android (Lollipop)

Tags: android, google-chrome, audio, webrtc, getusermedia

Based on previous thread, *getUserMedia* is supported in Chrome on Android now (version 40).

I got this working using the usual *getUserMedia* idiom (see, for example, http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/).
This works on desktop (any mic) and on mobile (default mic).

However, when a USB mic is plugged in, this does not seem to work. The usual permission dialog is shown. However, the input audio will actually come from the phone's default mic (ie, scratching/tapping the usb mic produced no noise), even though the USBmic is clearly connected (ie, it lit up).

On desktop, you can fix this by selecting the audio input source, but I'm not sure how to do that on **Android**.

The really funny thing is that typical audio recording APPs can actually CORRECTLY get the audio input from the USB mic on the same device.

Has anyone experienced this problem?

Comment: maybe i share this, its my post from now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62126741/recording-usb-audio-input-on-android-9-10

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this issue it appears to be specific to some Android phones and Android tablet devices that I have tested, including a Samsung Tab A7 and the Amazon Fire 10".

Currently testing Samsung Tab A7 with Chrome 103.0.5060.129 Android 11; SM-T220 Build/RP1A.200720.012

I do not have this issue in chrome on my Android Oneplus 8 running Android 11.

More information for reproducing:
The expected behavior does not work in Chrome, but does work as expected in Firefox.

1. Plug in an external USB microphone device
2. Open a site such as https://vdo.ninja/ or a https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/
3. Capture audio.

The default audio will be captured from the devices internal microphone instead of the USB microphone.

On sites such as the vdo.ninja, where you are able to select the audio source, even if the source is listed, such as "Wired Headset", changing the input will result in using the internal microphone.